# Mysql difference between max() and min()?

Tags: mysql, function, max

I got a problem with a mySql query and max() function.
If I do :

```
Select * from Data group by experiment having min(timestamp)
```

This query return what I want, and correct value.
I got this :

```
+----------+---------+----------+---------------------+----------------+------------+
| id       | mote_id | label_id | timestamp           | value          | experiment |
+----------+---------+----------+---------------------+----------------+------------+
|  3768806 |      10 |       30 | 2014-04-22 14:37:07 |              0 |         13 |
| 10989209 |      12 |       22 | 2014-04-25 10:44:03 | 2.532958984375 |         15 |
| 11943537 |       6 |       19 | 2014-05-05 17:20:15 |           1228 |         16 |
| 12042549 |      16 |       26 | 2014-05-06 10:48:59 |          22.86 |         17 |
| 12176642 |      15 |       23 | 2014-05-07 15:19:35 |              0 |         18 |
| 12195344 |      10 |        6 | 2014-05-07 15:27:23 |           3460 |         19 |
| 12222470 |      15 |        8 | 2014-05-07 15:38:38 |              1 |         21 |
| 12343934 |      10 |       19 | 2014-05-12 10:35:42 |            742 |         23 |
+----------+---------+----------+---------------------+----------------+------------+
```

But, if i do :

```
Select * from Data group by experiment having max(timestamp)
```

This query return wrong values... like this :

```
+----------+---------+----------+---------------------+----------------+------------+
| id       | mote_id | label_id | timestamp           | value          | experiment |
+----------+---------+----------+---------------------+----------------+------------+
|  3768806 |      10 |       30 | 2014-04-22 14:37:07 |              0 |         13 |
| 10989209 |      12 |       22 | 2014-04-25 10:44:03 | 2.532958984375 |         15 |
| 11943537 |       6 |       19 | 2014-05-05 17:20:15 |           1228 |         16 |
| 12042549 |      16 |       26 | 2014-05-06 10:48:59 |          22.86 |         17 |
| 12176642 |      15 |       23 | 2014-05-07 15:19:35 |              0 |         18 |
| 12195344 |      10 |        6 | 2014-05-07 15:27:23 |           3460 |         19 |
| 12222470 |      15 |        8 | 2014-05-07 15:38:38 |              1 |         21 |
| 12343934 |      10 |       19 | 2014-05-12 10:35:42 |            742 |         23 |
+----------+---------+----------+---------------------+----------------+------------+
```

In the first query, if I replace `min(timestamp)` by `timestamp=min(timestamp)`, it works, but in the second, `"timestamp=max(timestamp)"` return **nothing**

Finally, `Select experiment,max(timestamp)` return correct values.

mysql> select *,max(timestamp) from Data group by experiment;

```
+----------+---------+----------+---------------------+----------------+------------+---------------------+
| id       | mote_id | label_id | timestamp           | value          | experiment | max(timestamp)      |
+----------+---------+----------+---------------------+----------------+------------+---------------------+
|  3768806 |      10 |       30 | 2014-04-22 14:37:07 |              0 |         13 | 2014-04-24 16:03:29 |
| 10989209 |      12 |       22 | 2014-04-25 10:44:03 | 2.532958984375 |         15 | 2014-05-05 10:34:35 |
| 11943537 |       6 |       19 | 2014-05-05 17:20:15 |           1228 |         16 | 2014-05-06 10:35:15 |
| 12042549 |      16 |       26 | 2014-05-06 10:48:59 |          22.86 |         17 | 2014-05-07 15:19:33 |
| 12176642 |      15 |       23 | 2014-05-07 15:19:35 |              0 |         18 | 2014-05-07 15:27:23 |
| 12195344 |      10 |        6 | 2014-05-07 15:27:23 |           3460 |         19 | 2014-05-07 15:38:01 |
| 12222470 |      15 |        8 | 2014-05-07 15:38:38 |              1 |         21 | 2014-05-07 16:30:38 |
| 12343934 |      10 |       19 | 2014-05-12 10:35:42 |            742 |         23 | 2014-05-14 09:25:44 |
+----------+---------+----------+---------------------+----------------+------------+---------------------+
```

I know I can make a subquery to solve my probleme, but the tables contains thousands rows, and this solution is too long...

Ps : I can't use `Select*, max(timestamp)` even if it works because the query is run by EJB in JEE.

Comment: Maybe some sample values reproducing the problem could help.

Comment: `HAVING` clause expects a `key-value` pair instead of just value. `max` and `min` return the maximum and minimum value of the column specified respectively

Comment: @asprin no it isn't It expects _boolean expression_ like any conditional filter. Thus, OP's expression is fine - you can use non-boolean things in conditions - they just will be implicitly converted to boolean. That's why `max()` and `min()` may be not same. For example, 0 will be treated as false and 1000 as true

Comment: My bad..ignore my comment

Comment: `Select * from Data group by experiment` is invalid SQL (Though, mysql, unlike other SQL dbs, will not report an error on it). The issue is you are grouping on the "experiment" column, so what should be returned in the other columns ? It can be pretty random, and you normally do not want SQL statements to return rather random data. Any column you mention in `select ...` that is NOT an aggregate (i.e. min(), sum(), etc. ) must also appear in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: "This query return what I want" Er, I doubt that - by which I mean that the HAVING bit is redundant

Comment: @Strawberry It's the correct values, I check that manually ;)

Comment: :-) It's your good fortune that the timestamps follow the same order as the PRIMARY KEY (id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You select not determined values grouped by field `experiment`. No one can give you a guarantee that non-agregated fields would correspond to MIN or MAX values of some aggregated field.

You HAVE TO use sub-query or self-join to get the right records.

See more here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: Thanks, so it's not possible without subrequest... I tried, it take over 30 min to execute this (currently there is about 3 millions rows in my table...).

Comment: Did you use sub request in your JOIN statement or in WHERE?
You should create your temporary table once (in JOIN table). If you use sub request in WHERE clause it will be executed again for every row.

Answer (score 0):

The `HAVING` clause expects a boolean expression. In other DBMS your code sample would trigger an error. In MySQL, you'll get the expression cast to boolean:

- Zero → false
- Non-zero → true

And since your expression is constant for the whole set, it won't filter out partial rows.

As about this:

```
HAVING timestamp = max(timestamp)
```

The `HAVING` clause evaluates *after* `WHERE` and `GROUP BY`. At that point, using individual row values of the `timestamp` column doesn't make any sense. As usual, [MySQL allows that](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html) but you must take into account that:

> In standard SQL, a query that includes a GROUP BY clause cannot refer
>   to nonaggregated columns in the HAVING clause that are not named in
>   the GROUP BY clause. **A MySQL extension permits references to such
>   columns to simplify calculations. This extension assumes that the
>   nongrouped columns will have the same group-wise values. Otherwise,
>   the result is indeterminate.**

In other words, your results are arbitrary (not even random).

Comment: So 'having timestamp = max(timestamp)' should works no ? It's correct boolean expression...

Comment: It will work! But the result will not be as you want.

Comment: @user3394487 - I've edited the question and added a quote from the manual.